# Need to run a code behind function from another aspx's code behind

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is there a way to call code behind function with Javascript that is in another aspx page's code behind?

Comment: Can you share what it is you're trying to do this for?  This smells of something where there's probably a much simpler way to do accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Are you talking about calling code-behind from client-side javascript? You aren't going to be able to call any code directly on the server from the client without sending a request to the web page, in which case the fact that it is another aspx page is a moot point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to expose the method as a [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.90%29.aspx).

You could then call it using something like the [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.